# find $\angle{BDE}$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

[image]

All information required is shown at the picture

the only thing I could find is this equation:
$\angle{BDE}$ + $\angle{CED}$ = 80 .
 I don't know what to do...

Comment: What did you try? Where is the effort you put?

Comment: I found all the angles except BDE  and CED ...

Comment: Did you find angles BDC and BEC?  If F is the intersection of segments EC and BD, can you find the angles CFD, DFE, BFE, BFC?

Comment: yes these angles are easy to find...

Comment: i have used the theorem of sines and cosines

Answer (score 2):

i have three equations:
$$a^2=ED^2+BD^2-2ED\cdot BD\cos(x)$$
$$\frac{\sin(50^{\circ}}{\sin(x)}=\frac{ED}{a}$$
$$\frac{\sin(70^{\circ})}{\sin(80^{\circ})}=\frac{a}{BD}$$